# "I can hardly wait for baby coming"

Tags: grammar, usage

> I can hardly wait to cut the cake.
>   I can hardly wait for baby coming.

Is "can hardly" correctly used in the sentences above?

Comment: Yes. Completely correct

Comment: The second sentence '... wait for baby coming' doesn't seem right though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct, the second should be "I can hardly wait for the baby to come" -- of course "the" could be replaced by "our"/"my"/"your"/"my sister's" etc. as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly wait = I am extremely excited

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Not always. It can also mean "waiting for *X* would be impractical or impossible": *I can hardly wait for Mr. Jones here to tell me who killed him, can I?*

Comment: While it could technically be used that way, the first sense is so common and idiomatic that you would likely be misunderstood if you tried to say that.